Trouble logging into ubuntu using a windows AD
I followed this guide to connect my ubuntu 24 lts server to a windows domain. It's able to pull user details, and even seems to verify a password, but then gives a system error when trying to log in. I can't find anything in any of the SSSD logs that denote an issue. the closest I found was in the sssd_pac.log that said "Pac check is set but pac responder is not running". Any help would be fantastic.
